# Split an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How to get a sections of a single image using javascript and store it in an array, and later display randomly on html5 canvas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the clipping parameters of the drawImage() method and draw your clipped image onto a dynamically created canvas.

An example could be:

```
function getClippedRegion(image, x, y, width, height) {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    //                   source region         dest. region
    ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height,  0, 0, width, height);

    return canvas;
}
```

This will return a canvas element with the clipped image drawn in already. You can now use the canvas directly to draw it onto another canvas.

Example of usage; in your main code you can do:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myScreenCanvas'),
    ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    image  = document.getElementById('myImageId'),
    clip   = getClippedRegion(image, 50, 20, 100, 100);

// draw the clipped image onto the on-screen canvas
ctx.drawImage(clip, canvas.width * Math.random(), canvas.height * Math.random());
```

Answer (score 4):

....Or you can just use the CSS sprite technique which is faster and easier.

If you have an image(my_Image.gif for example) and you intend to extract only a portion using this method, you can simulate the extract as a background of a DIV element . See the code below.

**portion1** id parameters below simply say "From my image, slice 100px high and 100px wide from position 0px to the left(margin-left) and 0px to the top(margin-top)"

**portion2** id parameters below simply say "From my image, slice 100px high and 100px wide from position -91px to the left(margin-left) and 0px to the top(margin-top)"

With this, you can slice any size from any position by simply manipulating the pixels. You can also use % as well.

Note: Your image must be in gif format in this case and must be residing in the root of your server...

You can use other image extensions...jpeg, png etc.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <style>

            #portion1 {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background: url(my_Image.gif) 0 0;
            }

            #portion2 {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background: url(my_Image.gif) -91px 0;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>


             <div id="portion1"></div><br>
             <div id="portion2"></div>


              <script>
               //creating the array to hold the portions
               var ImagePortions = [
               "url('my_Image.gif') 0 0 ",
               "url('my_Image.gif') -91px 0"];

/*You can now create your canvas container that will act as the parent  of these array elements and use Math.random() to display the portions*/


       </script>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Nice idea, simple and sweet. Thanks